Why was my question on an issue with an SDK closed as not about software development?
I asked this question about port forwarding with the node ngrok sdk. The question shows code in a minimal form and is about express and ngrok.
However, just a day after posting I got 2 close votes, 2 downvotes, and 1 upvote. The questions was closed for:

This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read the on-topic page for a site before posting there.

I don't believe this was closed for a valid reason but I would be interested to hear what more experienced users think.

If the problem was with the ngrok configuration, I could see it being closed as off-topic (since computer configuration is mostly considered not "specific to programming"). However, that assumes the solution already whereas the question seems at the crossroads and no one has left a comment declaring it definitely to be an ngrok configuration issue. Who's to say it isn't an express issue and thus definitely on-topic?

FYI I cast the last vote but mine was for "Needs detail or clarity". I've left a follow up comment / question

Arguably, the question is still far from minimal. I'd try reproducing this bug with a simple "Hello world" example first.

I think this is one of those cases where the close reason is wrong, but the question isn't in a condition to be reopened yet (based on the clarifying questions posed in the comments below it). I suspect that some voters saw "server configuration" and CV'd as off topic for that reason... the line is historically fuzzy, but because you included code I really can't see how it applies, personally. But if your question is still unclear, it's not worth reopening until that issue is also resolved.

This question was deleted. It was caused by a logic issue in the scope of the question and is hence no longer reproducible as well as being unfocused.
For other posters out there remember even if your question was closed for the wrong reason it still can remain close if there are major issues with it.

Yeah..., even if the Qt was closed for "the uncorrect reason" (it's often 2 Closers with 1 reason, or 3 Closers with all a different reason, the "System" just picks the last one), you could still have improved your Qt... I was an early "noticer" of your 'Meta'-Qt and gave you some advice, but you only followed about 30-40% of it, all my previous Comments now deleted. but I told you exactly like what's in all the +4/+7/+6 Comments (+ more), Qt (on 'Main') ended up at -4 as I can see (<10k, but I still had the Tab open), and I gave some specific advice to avoid DV's but that got ignored...

@chivracq If all 3 have different reasons, it doesn't pick up the last, it just gets closed as a generic not on topic for SO.

@M, Oh...!, yep-yep, I'm not "too versed" in the "finesses" and "fine prints" of the Closing-System, I just knew it was "a bit weird sometimes", from the many-many Threads on 'Meta'...

@chivracq And if two voters pick the same reason, that reason is picked unless at least one vote was for migration, then it will do the same (generic off-topic message) as if all three voted differently. The only exception is if a duplicate vote is cast by someone with a gold-hammer, then that applies. So, it never picks just the last vote.

None of the above descriptions of how the system picks the reason are quite right, as the actual answer is that it's chosen by a surprisingly complicated algorithm.  But in relevant part: three different reasons makes it pick the first, not the last or a generic reason, unless two of them were for different community-specific reasons (and I don't think there is any special-casing of at least one vote being for migration).
